# display special characters in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

How to display right content on jsp page or any configuration need to done in  tomcat server...?

display at jsp : `Hello G�nter`

original content :  `Hello Günter`

We do the following but its not working.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15"   
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the charset to UTF-8?

Comment: Why is your contentType and pageEncoding different?

Comment: Why did you choose a different charset in contentType and pageEncoding? Unless you really know what you are doing, I suggest you use UTF8 everywhere, also the database storage and communications with the database (if you use a database).

Comment: no i just use jsp page no communication with database

Comment: What editor do you use? Notepad++ for instance likes to save pages in ANSI mode.

Comment: no i am using eclipse IDE for editing page

Comment: "ü" is not "special", it's a character like any other character.

Comment: yes but how to display on page

Comment: What server are you using and what JSP container?

Comment: i am using apache tomcat for jsp container

Answer (score 2):

As most other people have said, you should probably check the encoding of the actual file *on the file system*. Even if the server is instructed to serve out UTF-8, if the file is mangled, you'll get the wrong output.

Among the most common tools, you can use Notepad++ or Eclipse to check the encoding of the file. In Notepad++, open the file and click the **Encoding** tab. Make sure that "Encode as UTF-8" is selected.

[image: Notepad++ encoding selection]

In eclipse, you need to right-click the file in the project explorer. In the **Resource** tab, the bottom property is "Text file encoding". Make sure that UTF-8 is selected there.

[image]

---

FYI, I had a similar encoding issue a while ago, on Weblogic. The order of the parameters in the attributes affected the way the page behaved. You can find more info [here](http://improve.ro/2010/08/weblogic-encoding-issue/), although I don't think it applies to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. If on Windows, install additional language pack.
2. Save the JSP file encoded in UTF-8.
3. Make charset and pageEncoding consistent.
4. Check your browser's encoding. Set it to UTF-8 as well.

Comment: not working i do the following <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

- If it is hard-coded HTML use HTML escape sequences.
- If the value is being picked up from a ResourceBundle, use unicode equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse defaults to your platform encoding when saving files. If you are on windows, this will most likely not be UTF-8. To change this, either right-click the file (jsp) in eclipse, click properties and at the bottom you can set the encoding it saves the file in.

To change the default content type in Eclipse, you can go to Windows->Preferences and under General / Content Types you can set default encoding to save as for different file types.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp page is OK. So make sure your browser's character encoding is UTF-8.